# Mac Terminal -bash warnings on start

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Upon opening a new Terminal window on my Mac, I always get the following message -

```
Last login: Wed xx xxxxx on xxxxx
-bash: export: `-s': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/xxxxxx/.rvm/scripts/rvm': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `]]': not a valid identifier
```

Although its not leading to any problems, how can I correct/get rid of the above? Thanks

Comment: Check the contents of `.bash_profile`; it's probably got some garbage in it.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include your `.bashrc` and/or `.bash_profile`. Or, just the offending lines? It looks like bash is not liking the usage of the export command. That could be triggered by something like this:

    `$ export -- -s`

Another suggestion to isolate the offending line(s) would be to test the script with bash's -x option set. This will print each executed command string before actually executing it. Just open up a new terminal window and try something like:

    `$ bash -x ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have set the bash to run some commands at the starting time.
Change the setting from Terminal Preference may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that you have a file executed on starting a terminal session? Normally this is something like `.profile` or `.bash_profile` in your home-folder.

As @Wobble already suggested it seems that execution of one of these files causes that problem.

I think it might be a missing backtick in an export statement.

Answer (score 0):

See also my comment under the question. But it looks like you probably just copy and mis-pasted a command to initialize the shell environment for Ruby `rvm` using `rvm`'s init script. I have a similar line in my .bashrc and it looks like this:

```
test -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I'm guessing yours is using bash's `[[` notation for the `test` command. If you want to stick with that syntax, the line should look like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

So, comb over your `.bashrc`'s `rvm` init line and make it look like one of the above.